# How to store segue identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the most widely used way of storing segue identifier. Is it using #define or NSString constant.

```
#define SEGUE_IDENTIFIER @"SegueIdentifer"
NSString * const SEGUE_IDENTIFIER = @"SegueIdentifer";
```

Comment: NSString constant is better in principle because you retain some type information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
static NSString * const SEGUE_IDENTIFIER = @"SegueIdentifier";
```